# I want to disable a horizontal scrollbar for moving divs (which move outside the screen) in my banner; but not for the rest of the content

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

My website http://dekomkommertijd.nl has a banner with moving clouds that I made with CSS animated (moving) div's. They enter left and when they leave the screen at the right side they create a horizontal scrollbar. Everything works as I want to, except I don't want the scrollbar, except for the content within my content div (canvas - with a width of 960px). Everything outside should be without a horizontal scrollbar and just leave the screen.

I tried several methods I found (mostly for static divs) but they don't work for my moving divs.

anybody knows how to fix this?

thanks.
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've described it suggests to me that you'd want your clouds and other content to overflow in different ways. The overflow is determined by the parent, so to handle the overflow differently you'd need to have two parents: one for the clouds, and one for the content.

If you choose to do it this way, setting the cloud parent to absolute positioning would take it out of the normal document flow so it doesn't interfere with the rest of your content. And setting the overflow makes it behave as you'd like.

```
width: 100%; /* Spans the whole document */
overflow-x: hidden; /* Hides overflow instead of displaying it */
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
```

Another solution would be handling the overflow identically for your clouds and other content. If you do it this way, you could just set it to be hidden on a mutual parent element, like the body.

This second solution might make more sense, as it's 1. simpler and 2. unlikely that you'll have anything other than the clouds overflowing.

Comment: But the clouds need to go over the other elements - for the visual element I am going for, so they need a higher z-index then the underlying layer. Is it also possible that way?

Comment: Oh, okay. I made the assumption you wanted them underneath. It'll work either way; the only thing that matters is overflow-x hiding the clouds.

Comment: I made a cloudlayer at the top of the body (using your CSS), with my clouds in it; but now all my clouds are invisible - independent of the z-index of the layer!? Can check on dekomkommertijd.nl

Comment: Ah, it might be because their parent has a height of 0. Try setting height:100% on html, body, and the cloud parent. Sorry, I'm on the bus or I'd make a JSFiddle!

Comment: Now one problem is left, the top right social media icons do not function anymore (cannot press, or hover) while the rest of the site does. And changing the z-index of the media div does not help either... (sorry for the thousand questions :))

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have thought of this when we kept the clouds on top of everything. Get rid of that `height: 100%;` stuff we set before. This will make your clouds 'invisible' again. What this means is that they're overflowing in the y direction but getting hidden. To make them display, change `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow-x: hidden;` so that it only affects the horizontal direction.

Comment: As soon as I put in overflow-x:hidden; it hides the clouds again :s

Comment: okay solved it. Put the social media div in the cloudlayer, and made the height of the cloud layer 300px so that it does not overlay my sidebar menu. The top-menu still has a overlay, but for some reason still works :s but this means that it works allright now :)... thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-y: hidden` from the following code:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Remove This Line */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

and apply following style on the body:

```
body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hopefully, it will work.